# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to build simple search tab with thymeleaf and Spring boot.
Here is my codes and html files.

scCountry.html

```
  <form class="form-inline" action="#"  th:action="@{/search}" modelAttribute="sInput" th:object="${sInput}" method="post">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" th:field="*{keyWord}">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <!--      <button class="btn btn-success" type="Submit" value="Submit">Search</button> -->
            </form>
```

Controller.class

```
 @GetMapping(value="/search")
    public String SearchForm(Model model) {

         SearchInput sInput = new SearchInput();
        model.addAttribute("sInput",sInput);

        return "scCountry";
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/search")
    public String SearchResult(@ModelAttribute("sInput") SearchInput sInput, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "scCountry";
        }

        SearchVO searchVO = null;
        try {
            searchVO = webServices.searchAll(sInput.getKeyWord());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        model.addAttribute("searchVO",searchVO);

        return "scSearch";
    }
```

Modal Class

```
public class SearchInput {

    private String keyWord;
    public String getKeyWord() {
        return keyWord;
    }
    public void setKeyWord(String keyWord) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
    }
    public SearchInput() {
    }
    public SearchInput(String keyWord) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
    }
}
```

Log

```
         :[Ljava.lang.Byte;@3929bes             :[Ljava.lang.Byte;@1995b82018-12-13 20:45:53.989 ERROR 6400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "scCountry": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "scCountry" - line 31, col 86)
```

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "scCountry" - line 31, col 86)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:354) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'sInput' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:305) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:252) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:226) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
... 56 common frames omitted

2018-12-13 20:45:54.002

### ERROR 6400 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "scCountry" - line 31, col 86)] with root cause java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'sInput' available as request attribute at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.

(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:305) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:252) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:226) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]

```
...
```

I am getting the error : Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'sInput' available as request attribute

I tried the solutions in below which is answered in this platform:

[html form validation using thymeleaf not working spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318401/html-form-validation-using-thymeleaf-not-working-spring-boot/35330380#35330380)

[Thymeleaf registration page - Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072304/thymeleaf-registration-page-error-during-execution-of-processor-org-thymeleaf)

[Spring Thymeleaf TemplateProcessingException in SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359208/spring-thymeleaf-templateprocessingexception-in-springinputgeneralfieldtagproces?rq=1)

[using search functionality in thymeleaf with request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681122/using-search-functionality-in-thymeleaf-with-request-parameters)

If I use the form like below,It is working.

```
<form class="form-inline"   action="/search" method="post">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"  id="keyWord" name="keyWord" value=""  placeholder="Search" >
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <!--      <button class="btn btn-success" type="Submit" value="Submit">Search</button> -->
            </form>
```

But I wondering what i am missing for two days?

Could anyone help me ?

I want to know why `th:object="${sInput}` in the scCountry.html is not fetching the object in the model which i put it in model with the same name?

Answer (score 4):

Was facing a similar problem.
This didn't work:

`<input type="text" th:field="*{content}">`

This did:

`<input type="text" field="*{content}" name="content">`

Answer (score 2):

```
th:field="*{sInput.keyWord}"
```

should be

```
th:field="*{keyWord}"
```

When using `*{...}` expressions, the `th:object` is assumed.

Comment: I tried it.But nothing has changed.Also according to the error description,  th:object="${sInput}" is not available before than keyWord.I am editing the question as "*{keyWord}"

Comment: So what happens when you print out `<span th:text="${sInput} />` on the same page?  I'm guessing it's null somehow, and not actually being added to the model?

Comment: I added the error log and Model Class in the above.I am getting the error : "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "scCountry" - line 31, col 86)". Also the page is not opening.The error is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

Simply take off the "th:" from the "th:field" and you are good to go!

Comment: why this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Do the below modifications in your controller and try

```
@GetMapping(value="/search")

public ModelAndView SearchForm(Model model, SearchInput sInput) {

    return new ModelAndView("scCountry");

}
```

Hope you will get solved your error.

Answer (score 0):

A was have the same proplem. That helped me. Old code -

```
@PostMapping()
public String create(@Valid AdditionalContact additionalContact, BindingResult bindingResult, BindingResult bindingResultForId, Model model) {
   if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || bindingResultForId.hasErrors())
        model.addAttribute("contacts", additionalContact.getAll());
    return "additionalContact/create";
    additionalContactService.save(additionalContact);
    return "redirect:contacts";
    }
```

new code

```
@PostMapping()
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("contact") AdditionalContact additionalContact, BindingResult bindingResult,
                         BindingResult bindingResultForId) {

if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || bindingResultForId.hasErrors())
return "additionalContact/create";

additionalContactService.save(additionalContact);
return "redirect:contacts";
}
```